# Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm a beginner in React and at the moment I try to connect my first app to a Firebase database.

I have two files for that. The first, is a config.js file where all the information about the database are stored, like this:

```
`export default {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    databaseURL: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***"
  };`
```

And my other file, App.js:

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

//Firebase
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import config from 'firebase';


class App extends Component {
constructor () {
    super()

    this.state = { loading: true }
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    const capsRef = firebase.database().ref('Capsules')

    capsRef.on('value', snapshot => {
      this.setState({
        Capsules: snapshot.val(),
        loading: false
      })
    })
  }

  render () {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <p>Je suis en train de charger.</p>
      )
    }

    const capsRef = Object.keys(this.state.tweets).map(key => {
      return <p key={key}>{this.state.Capsules[key].designation}</p>
    })

    return (
      <div>


        <h1>Test</h1>

      </div>

    )
  }
}

export default App;`
```

So, when I refresh my browser, I have an error message : "Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)."

Can anyone help me ? 
It's been a week now that I'm looking for a solution by myself.

Comment: Can you show your config file?

Comment: Hello Collin, thank a lot for your help ! In my config file, I just have my database information write exactly like  in my first post.

Comment: You'll need to somehow make sure that `initializeApp` is called only once.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your code, but you could try:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

in your config file.

Comment: This helped me while building a web app Flutter (a completely different language). Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear! It seems to be common to all the Firebase libraries :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example with Firebase 9 / Modular using TypeScript. Just use `initializeAppIfNecessary()` to get access to the app. If you want to make this even cleaner, extract this out to a file called `firebase.ts` and export this function

```
import { initializeApp, getApp } from "firebase/app";

function initializeAppIfNecessary() {
  try {
    return getApp();
  } catch (any) {
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      projectId: "...",
    };
    return initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  }
}

const app = initializeAppIfNecessary();
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Safe way to Initializing a Firebase App**

Before you call the initialize app function, you must to ensure there's no same app that has been initialized before.

How to do that?

Let's try the examples below.

---

**Firebase v9 (*Modular*)**

```js
import { initializeApp, getApp } from 'firebase/app'

let fireapp

try {
    fireapp = getApp()
} catch (error) {
    fireapp = initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'xxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxx',
        databaseURL: 'xxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxxx',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxxx',
        appId: 'xxxx',
    })
}
```

Why we use `try/catch` block? Because, if `getApp` function can't find any existing App in the browser, it will throw an error instead of return a `undefined` value.

---

**Firebase v8 (*Legacy, Namespaced*)**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'xxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxx',
        databaseURL: 'xxxx',
        projectId: 'xxxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxxx',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxxx',
        appId: 'xxxx',
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you trying to initialize firebase again and again. It should be initialized at once and use to avoid Firebase app named '[DEFAULT]' already exists you have to change your initialization style.

```
try {
firebase.initializeApp({
apiKey: "FULL_API_KEY_PUT_HERE",
authDomain: "FULL_AUTHDOMAIN_PUT_HERE",
databaseURL: "https://FULL_databaseURL_PUT_HERE.com",
storageBucket: "FULL_storageBucket_PUT_HEREappspot.com",
})
} catch (err) {
// we skip the "already exists" message which is
// not an actual error when we're hot-reloading
if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
console.error('Firebase initialization error raised', err.stack)
}}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my App I'm initialising Firebase twice with 2 different configuration as I'd like to connect to 2 different projects (realtime database). Is it possible? If yes, what's the workaround? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check all places where you have initialised firebase app. Make sure there is any mismatch among all configs of firebase. Hopefully it will be resolved.